# tomcat login with mongodb nullpointerexception

Tags: java, mongodb, tomcat, authentication

I'm trying to authenticate myself on a tomcat servlet with credentials stocked on a mongodb database. Basically I've tried to follow this tutorial :
http://www.locked.de/2014/03/11/tomcat-mongodb-authentication-realm/
I've got this in my context.xml :

```
<Realm 
 authDB="test"
 authCollection="user" 
 authUserField="username" 
 authPasswordField="password" 
 authRoleField="" 
 className="de.locked.tomcat.mongorealm.GenericMongoRealm"
 defaultDbHost="localhost" 
 defaultDbPass="user1" 
 defaultDbUser="user1" 
 defaultRole="user"
 digest = "SHA-256"/>
```

this in the web.xml :

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>auth</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>

    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>user</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>

<login-config>
    <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
    <realm-name>Basic Authentication</realm-name>
</login-config>
```

in mongo :

```
> use test
switched to db test
> show users
{
    "_id" : "test.user1",
    "user" : "user1",
    "db" : "test",
    "roles" : [
        {
            "role" : "dbAdmin",
            "db" : "test"
        }
    ]
}
```

but after having one time typed the username and password, I got this :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    de.locked.tomcat.mongorealm.GenericMongoRealm.getPassword(GenericMongoRealm.java:105)
    org.apache.catalina.realm.RealmBase.authenticate(RealmBase.java:381)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.BasicAuthenticator.authenticate(BasicAuthenticator.java:141)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:577)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:620)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Here's the part of the log :

```
2015-05-07T17:43:51.722+0200 I NETWORK  [conn146] end connection 127.0.0.1:55372 (1 connection now open)
2015-05-07T17:43:51.733+0200 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:55382 #151 (2 connections now open)
2015-05-07T17:43:51.733+0200 I ACCESS   [conn151]  authenticate db: admin { authenticate: 1, user: "user1", nonce: "xxx", key: "xxx" }
2015-05-07T17:43:51.733+0200 I ACCESS   [conn151] Failed to authenticate user1@admin with mechanism MONGODB-CR: AuthenticationFailed UserNotFound Could not find user user1@admin
2015-05-07T17:43:51.793+0200 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:55383 #152 (3 connections now open)
2015-05-07T17:43:51.794+0200 I ACCESS   [conn152]  authenticate db: admin { authenticate: 1, user: "user1", nonce: "xxx", key: "xxx" }
2015-05-07T17:43:51.794+0200 I ACCESS   [conn152] Failed to authenticate user1@admin with mechanism MONGODB-CR: AuthenticationFailed UserNotFound Could not find user user1@admin
2015-05-07T17:43:51.849+0200 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:55384 #153 (4 connections now open)
2015-05-07T17:43:51.851+0200 I ACCESS   [conn153]  authenticate db: admin { authenticate: 1, user: "user1", nonce: "xxx", key: "xxx" }
2015-05-07T17:43:51.851+0200 I ACCESS   [conn153] Failed to authenticate user1@admin with mechanism MONGODB-CR: AuthenticationFailed UserNotFound Could not find user user1@admin
2015-05-07T17:43:51.925+0200 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:55385 #154 (5 connections now open)
2015-05-07T17:43:51.926+0200 I ACCESS   [conn154]  authenticate db: admin { authenticate: 1, user: "user1", nonce: "xxx", key: "xxx" }
2015-05-07T17:43:51.926+0200 I ACCESS   [conn154] Failed to authenticate user1@admin with mechanism MONGODB-CR: AuthenticationFailed UserNotFound Could not find user user1@admin
2015-05-07T17:43:51.983+0200 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:55386 #155 (6 connections now open)
2015-05-07T17:43:51.983+0200 I ACCESS   [conn155]  authenticate db: admin { authenticate: 1, user: "user1", nonce: "xxx", key: "xxx" }
2015-05-07T17:43:51.984+0200 I ACCESS   [conn155] Failed to authenticate user1@admin with mechanism MONGODB-CR: AuthenticationFailed UserNotFound Could not find user user1@admin
2015-05-07T17:44:02.094+0200 I NETWORK  [conn153] end connection 127.0.0.1:55384 (5 connections now open)
2015-05-07T17:44:02.112+0200 I NETWORK  [conn155] end connection 127.0.0.1:55386 (4 connections now open)
2015-05-07T17:44:02.117+0200 I NETWORK  [conn151] end connection 127.0.0.1:55382 (3 connections now open)
2015-05-07T17:44:02.121+0200 I NETWORK  [conn154] end connection 127.0.0.1:55385 (2 connections now open)
2015-05-07T17:44:02.124+0200 I NETWORK  [conn152] end connection 127.0.0.1:55383 (1 connection now open)
2015-05-07T17:44:02.136+0200 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:55389 #156 (2 connections now open)
2015-05-07T17:44:02.137+0200 I ACCESS   [conn156]  authenticate db: test { authenticate: 1, user: "user1", nonce: "xxx", key: "xxx" }
2015-05-07T17:44:02.137+0200 I ACCESS   [conn156] Failed to authenticate user1@test with mechanism MONGODB-CR: AuthenticationFailed MONGODB-CR credentials missing in the user document
2015-05-07T17:44:02.194+0200 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:55390 #157 (3 connections now open)
2015-05-07T17:44:02.195+0200 I ACCESS   [conn157]  authenticate db: test { authenticate: 1, user: "user1", nonce: "xxx", key: "xxx" }
2015-05-07T17:44:02.195+0200 I ACCESS   [conn157] Failed to authenticate user1@test with mechanism MONGODB-CR: AuthenticationFailed MONGODB-CR credentials missing in the user document
2015-05-07T17:44:02.272+0200 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:55391 #158 (4 connections now open)
2015-05-07T17:44:02.272+0200 I ACCESS   [conn158]  authenticate db: test { authenticate: 1, user: "user1", nonce: "xxx", key: "xxx" }
2015-05-07T17:44:02.272+0200 I ACCESS   [conn158] Failed to authenticate user1@test with mechanism MONGODB-CR: AuthenticationFailed MONGODB-CR credentials missing in the user document
2015-05-07T17:44:02.319+0200 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:55392 #159 (5 connections now open)
2015-05-07T17:44:02.320+0200 I ACCESS   [conn159]  authenticate db: test { authenticate: 1, user: "user1", nonce: "xxx", key: "xxx" }
2015-05-07T17:44:02.320+0200 I ACCESS   [conn159] Failed to authenticate user1@test with mechanism MONGODB-CR: AuthenticationFailed MONGODB-CR credentials missing in the user document
2015-05-07T17:44:02.370+0200 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:55393 #160 (6 connections now open)
2015-05-07T17:44:02.370+0200 I ACCESS   [conn160]  authenticate db: test { authenticate: 1, user: "user1", nonce: "xxx", key: "xxx" }
2015-05-07T17:44:02.371+0200 I ACCESS   [conn160] Failed to authenticate user1@test with mechanism MONGODB-CR: AuthenticationFailed MONGODB-CR credentials missing in the user document
2015-05-07T17:44:03.778+0200 I NETWORK  [conn158] end connection 127.0.0.1:55391 (5 connections now open)
2015-05-07T17:44:03.786+0200 I NETWORK  [conn160] end connection 127.0.0.1:55393 (4 connections now open)
2015-05-07T17:44:03.789+0200 I NETWORK  [conn156] end connection 127.0.0.1:55389 (3 connections now open)
2015-05-07T17:44:03.792+0200 I NETWORK  [conn159] end connection 127.0.0.1:55392 (2 connections now open)
2015-05-07T17:44:03.794+0200 I NETWORK  [conn157] end connection 127.0.0.1:55390 (1 connection now open)
2015-05-07T17:44:05.184+0200 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:55397 #161 (2 connections now open)
2015-05-07T17:44:05.192+0200 I ACCESS   [conn161]  authenticate db: test { authenticate: 1, user: "user1", nonce: "xxx", key: "xxx" }
2015-05-07T17:44:05.192+0200 I ACCESS   [conn161] Failed to authenticate user1@test with mechanism MONGODB-CR: AuthenticationFailed MONGODB-CR credentials missing in the user document
2015-05-07T17:44:05.432+0200 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:55398 #162 (3 connections now open)
2015-05-07T17:44:05.433+0200 I ACCESS   [conn162]  authenticate db: test { authenticate: 1, user: "user1", nonce: "xxx", key: "xxx" }
2015-05-07T17:44:05.433+0200 I ACCESS   [conn162] Failed to authenticate user1@test with mechanism MONGODB-CR: AuthenticationFailed MONGODB-CR credentials missing in the user document
2015-05-07T17:44:05.514+0200 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:55399 #163 (4 connections now open)
2015-05-07T17:44:05.514+0200 I ACCESS   [conn163]  authenticate db: test { authenticate: 1, user: "user1", nonce: "xxx", key: "xxx" }
2015-05-07T17:44:05.515+0200 I ACCESS   [conn163] Failed to authenticate user1@test with mechanism MONGODB-CR: AuthenticationFailed MONGODB-CR credentials missing in the user document
2015-05-07T17:44:05.583+0200 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:55400 #164 (5 connections now open)
2015-05-07T17:44:05.587+0200 I ACCESS   [conn164]  authenticate db: test { authenticate: 1, user: "user1", nonce: "xxx", key: "xxx" }
2015-05-07T17:44:05.587+0200 I ACCESS   [conn164] Failed to authenticate user1@test with mechanism MONGODB-CR: AuthenticationFailed MONGODB-CR credentials missing in the user document
2015-05-07T17:44:05.669+0200 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:55401 #165 (6 connections now open)
2015-05-07T17:44:05.670+0200 I ACCESS   [conn165]  authenticate db: test { authenticate: 1, user: "user1", nonce: "xxx", key: "xxx" }
2015-05-07T17:44:05.670+0200 I ACCESS   [conn165] Failed to authenticate user1@test with mechanism MONGODB-CR: AuthenticationFailed MONGODB-CR credentials missing in the user document
2015-05-07T17:44:21.378+0200 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:55405 #166 (7 connections now open)
2015-05-07T17:56:31.253+0200 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:55662 #167 (8 connections now open)
2015-05-07T17:57:41.596+0200 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:55676 #168 (9 connections now open)
2015-05-07T17:57:46.581+0200 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:55678 #169 (10 connections now open)
2015-05-07T17:57:51.596+0200 I NETWORK  [conn167] end connection 127.0.0.1:55662 (9 connections now open)
2015-05-07T17:57:54.044+0200 I NETWORK  [conn163] end connection 127.0.0.1:55399 (8 connections now open)
2015-05-07T17:57:54.044+0200 I NETWORK  [conn166] end connection 127.0.0.1:55405 (7 connections now open)
2015-05-07T17:57:54.045+0200 I NETWORK  [conn168] end connection 127.0.0.1:55676 (6 connections now open)
2015-05-07T17:57:54.045+0200 I NETWORK  [conn169] end connection 127.0.0.1:55678 (5 connections now open)
2015-05-07T17:57:54.052+0200 I NETWORK  [conn165] end connection 127.0.0.1:55401 (4 connections now open)
2015-05-07T17:57:54.054+0200 I NETWORK  [conn161] end connection 127.0.0.1:55397 (3 connections now open)
2015-05-07T17:57:54.057+0200 I NETWORK  [conn164] end connection 127.0.0.1:55400 (2 connections now open)
2015-05-07T17:57:54.059+0200 I NETWORK  [conn162] end connection 127.0.0.1:55398 (1 connection now open)
2015-05-07T17:57:56.395+0200 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:55683 #170 (2 connections now open)
2015-05-07T17:57:56.400+0200 I ACCESS   [conn170]  authenticate db: test { authenticate: 1, user: "user1", nonce: "xxx", key: "xxx" }
2015-05-07T17:57:56.401+0200 I ACCESS   [conn170] Failed to authenticate user1@test with mechanism MONGODB-CR: AuthenticationFailed MONGODB-CR credentials missing in the user document
2015-05-07T17:57:56.620+0200 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:55684 #171 (3 connections now open)
2015-05-07T17:57:56.621+0200 I ACCESS   [conn171]  authenticate db: test { authenticate: 1, user: "user1", nonce: "xxx", key: "xxx" }
2015-05-07T17:57:56.621+0200 I ACCESS   [conn171] Failed to authenticate user1@test with mechanism MONGODB-CR: AuthenticationFailed MONGODB-CR credentials missing in the user document
2015-05-07T17:57:56.699+0200 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:55685 #172 (4 connections now open)
2015-05-07T17:57:56.700+0200 I ACCESS   [conn172]  authenticate db: test { authenticate: 1, user: "user1", nonce: "xxx", key: "xxx" }
2015-05-07T17:57:56.700+0200 I ACCESS   [conn172] Failed to authenticate user1@test with mechanism MONGODB-CR: AuthenticationFailed MONGODB-CR credentials missing in the user document
2015-05-07T17:57:56.769+0200 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:55686 #173 (5 connections now open)
2015-05-07T17:57:56.770+0200 I ACCESS   [conn173]  authenticate db: test { authenticate: 1, user: "user1", nonce: "xxx", key: "xxx" }
2015-05-07T17:57:56.770+0200 I ACCESS   [conn173] Failed to authenticate user1@test with mechanism MONGODB-CR: AuthenticationFailed MONGODB-CR credentials missing in the user document
2015-05-07T17:57:56.846+0200 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:55687 #174 (6 connections now open)
2015-05-07T17:57:56.847+0200 I ACCESS   [conn174]  authenticate db: test { authenticate: 1, user: "user1", nonce: "xxx", key: "xxx" }
2015-05-07T17:57:56.847+0200 I ACCESS   [conn174] Failed to authenticate user1@test with mechanism MONGODB-CR: AuthenticationFailed MONGODB-CR credentials missing in the user document
2015-05-07T17:57:58.618+0200 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:55689 #175 (7 connections now open)
2015-05-07T17:58:03.250+0200 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:55694 #176 (8 connections now open)
2015-05-07T17:58:37.011+0200 I NETWORK  [conn175] end connection 127.0.0.1:55689 (7 connections now open)
2015-05-07T17:58:37.012+0200 I NETWORK  [conn172] end connection 127.0.0.1:55685 (6 connections now open)
2015-05-07T17:58:37.016+0200 I NETWORK  [conn176] end connection 127.0.0.1:55694 (5 connections now open)
2015-05-07T17:58:37.029+0200 I NETWORK  [conn174] end connection 127.0.0.1:55687 (4 connections now open)
2015-05-07T17:58:37.032+0200 I NETWORK  [conn170] end connection 127.0.0.1:55683 (3 connections now open)
2015-05-07T17:58:37.038+0200 I NETWORK  [conn173] end connection 127.0.0.1:55686 (2 connections now open)
2015-05-07T17:58:37.041+0200 I NETWORK  [conn171] end connection 127.0.0.1:55684 (1 connection now open)
2015-05-07T17:58:37.057+0200 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:55698 #177 (2 connections now open)
2015-05-07T17:58:37.058+0200 I ACCESS   [conn177]  authenticate db: test { authenticate: 1, user: "user1", nonce: "xxx", key: "xxx" }
2015-05-07T17:58:37.058+0200 I ACCESS   [conn177] Failed to authenticate user1@test with mechanism MONGODB-CR: AuthenticationFailed MONGODB-CR credentials missing in the user document
2015-05-07T17:58:37.116+0200 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:55701 #178 (3 connections now open)
2015-05-07T17:58:37.116+0200 I ACCESS   [conn178]  authenticate db: test { authenticate: 1, user: "user1", nonce: "xxx", key: "xxx" }
2015-05-07T17:58:37.116+0200 I ACCESS   [conn178] Failed to authenticate user1@test with mechanism MONGODB-CR: AuthenticationFailed MONGODB-CR credentials missing in the user document
2015-05-07T17:58:37.166+0200 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:55703 #179 (4 connections now open)
2015-05-07T17:58:37.167+0200 I ACCESS   [conn179]  authenticate db: test { authenticate: 1, user: "user1", nonce: "xxx", key: "xxx" }
2015-05-07T17:58:37.167+0200 I ACCESS   [conn179] Failed to authenticate user1@test with mechanism MONGODB-CR: AuthenticationFailed MONGODB-CR credentials missing in the user document
2015-05-07T17:58:37.230+0200 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:55704 #180 (5 connections now open)
2015-05-07T17:58:37.231+0200 I ACCESS   [conn180]  authenticate db: test { authenticate: 1, user: "user1", nonce: "xxx", key: "xxx" }
2015-05-07T17:58:37.231+0200 I ACCESS   [conn180] Failed to authenticate user1@test with mechanism MONGODB-CR: AuthenticationFailed MONGODB-CR credentials missing in the user document
2015-05-07T17:58:37.281+0200 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:55705 #181 (6 connections now open)
2015-05-07T17:58:37.282+0200 I ACCESS   [conn181]  authenticate db: test { authenticate: 1, user: "user1", nonce: "xxx", key: "xxx" }
2015-05-07T17:58:37.282+0200 I ACCESS   [conn181] Failed to authenticate user1@test with mechanism MONGODB-CR: AuthenticationFailed MONGODB-CR credentials missing in the user document
2015-05-07T17:58:37.384+0200 I NETWORK  [conn179] end connection 127.0.0.1:55703 (5 connections now open)
2015-05-07T17:58:37.390+0200 I NETWORK  [conn181] end connection 127.0.0.1:55705 (4 connections now open)
2015-05-07T17:58:37.392+0200 I NETWORK  [conn177] end connection 127.0.0.1:55698 (3 connections now open)
2015-05-07T17:58:37.394+0200 I NETWORK  [conn180] end connection 127.0.0.1:55704 (2 connections now open)
2015-05-07T17:58:37.396+0200 I NETWORK  [conn178] end connection 127.0.0.1:55701 (1 connection now open)
2015-05-07T17:58:38.653+0200 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:55706 #182 (2 connections now open)
2015-05-07T17:58:38.658+0200 I ACCESS   [conn182]  authenticate db: test { authenticate: 1, user: "user1", nonce: "xxx", key: "xxx" }
2015-05-07T17:58:38.659+0200 I ACCESS   [conn182] Failed to authenticate user1@test with mechanism MONGODB-CR: AuthenticationFailed MONGODB-CR credentials missing in the user document
2015-05-07T17:58:38.871+0200 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:55707 #183 (3 connections now open)
2015-05-07T17:58:38.872+0200 I ACCESS   [conn183]  authenticate db: test { authenticate: 1, user: "user1", nonce: "xxx", key: "xxx" }
2015-05-07T17:58:38.872+0200 I ACCESS   [conn183] Failed to authenticate user1@test with mechanism MONGODB-CR: AuthenticationFailed MONGODB-CR credentials missing in the user document
2015-05-07T17:58:38.947+0200 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:55708 #184 (4 connections now open)
2015-05-07T17:58:38.949+0200 I ACCESS   [conn184]  authenticate db: test { authenticate: 1, user: "user1", nonce: "xxx", key: "xxx" }
2015-05-07T17:58:38.949+0200 I ACCESS   [conn184] Failed to authenticate user1@test with mechanism MONGODB-CR: AuthenticationFailed MONGODB-CR credentials missing in the user document
2015-05-07T17:58:39.020+0200 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:55709 #185 (5 connections now open)
2015-05-07T17:58:39.021+0200 I ACCESS   [conn185]  authenticate db: test { authenticate: 1, user: "user1", nonce: "xxx", key: "xxx" }
2015-05-07T17:58:39.021+0200 I ACCESS   [conn185] Failed to authenticate user1@test with mechanism MONGODB-CR: AuthenticationFailed MONGODB-CR credentials missing in the user document
2015-05-07T17:58:39.098+0200 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:55710 #186 (6 connections now open)
2015-05-07T17:58:39.098+0200 I ACCESS   [conn186]  authenticate db: test { authenticate: 1, user: "user1", nonce: "xxx", key: "xxx" }
2015-05-07T17:58:39.098+0200 I ACCESS   [conn186] Failed to authenticate user1@test with mechanism MONGODB-CR: AuthenticationFailed MONGODB-CR credentials missing in the user document
2015-05-07T17:58:41.359+0200 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:55714 #187 (7 connections now open)
2015-05-07T17:58:58.066+0200 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:55718 #188 (8 connections now open)
2015-05-07T18:04:52.241+0200 I CONTROL  [signalProcessingThread] got signal 15 (Terminated), will terminate after current cmd ends
2015-05-07T18:04:52.241+0200 I CONTROL  [signalProcessingThread] now exiting
2015-05-07T18:04:52.241+0200 I NETWORK  [signalProcessingThread] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
2015-05-07T18:04:52.241+0200 I NETWORK  [signalProcessingThread] closing listening socket: 6
2015-05-07T18:04:52.241+0200 I NETWORK  [signalProcessingThread] closing listening socket: 7
2015-05-07T18:04:52.241+0200 I NETWORK  [signalProcessingThread] removing socket file: /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
2015-05-07T18:04:52.242+0200 I NETWORK  [signalProcessingThread] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
2015-05-07T18:04:52.242+0200 I NETWORK  [signalProcessingThread] shutdown: going to close sockets...
2015-05-07T18:04:52.242+0200 I STORAGE  [signalProcessingThread] shutdown: waiting for fs preallocator...
2015-05-07T18:04:52.242+0200 I STORAGE  [signalProcessingThread] shutdown: final commit...
2015-05-07T18:04:52.243+0200 I NETWORK  [conn185] end connection 127.0.0.1:55709 (7 connections now open)
2015-05-07T18:04:52.243+0200 I NETWORK  [conn186] end connection 127.0.0.1:55710 (7 connections now open)
2015-05-07T18:04:52.243+0200 I NETWORK  [conn183] end connection 127.0.0.1:55707 (7 connections now open)
2015-05-07T18:04:52.243+0200 I NETWORK  [conn184] end connection 127.0.0.1:55708 (7 connections now open)
2015-05-07T18:04:52.243+0200 I NETWORK  [conn40] end connection 127.0.0.1:51563 (4 connections now open)
2015-05-07T18:04:52.245+0200 I NETWORK  [conn188] end connection 127.0.0.1:55718 (3 connections now open)
2015-05-07T18:04:52.246+0200 I JOURNAL  [signalProcessingThread] journalCleanup...
2015-05-07T18:04:52.246+0200 I JOURNAL  [signalProcessingThread] removeJournalFiles
2015-05-07T18:04:52.255+0200 I NETWORK  [conn182] end connection 127.0.0.1:55706 (1 connection now open)
2015-05-07T18:04:52.255+0200 I NETWORK  [conn187] end connection 127.0.0.1:55714 (0 connections now open)
2015-05-07T18:04:52.255+0200 I JOURNAL  [signalProcessingThread] Terminating durability thread ...
2015-05-07T18:04:52.345+0200 I JOURNAL  [journal writer] Journal writer thread stopped
2015-05-07T18:04:52.345+0200 I JOURNAL  [durability] Durability thread stopped
2015-05-07T18:04:52.345+0200 I STORAGE  [signalProcessingThread] shutdown: closing all files...
2015-05-07T18:04:52.346+0200 I STORAGE  [signalProcessingThread] closeAllFiles() finished
2015-05-07T18:04:52.346+0200 I STORAGE  [signalProcessingThread] shutdown: removing fs lock...
2015-05-07T18:04:52.346+0200 I CONTROL  [signalProcessingThread] dbexit:  rc: 0
```

What is wrong with what I've done?
Thank you

Comment: `GenericMongoRealm` outputs some log messages on `initConnection`. If successful it should show: `realm authentication succeded: {0}` immediately following `connect to host: {0} / user: {1} / pass set: {2}`. Can you post the logging output?

Comment: I added it in the OP

Comment: For issues like this it would be helpful to include your driver & server version. It looks like you're trying to authenticate to a MongoDB 3.0 server using MONGODB-CR auth instead of the new default SCRAM-SHA-1: "MONGODB-CR credentials missing". You need to be using the 2.13 or newer Java driver for full [MongoDB 3.0 compatibility](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/drivers/java/#mongodb-compatibility). I would suggest following the tutorial in the [reference documentation](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/) matching the version of the MongoDB driver you are using (assuming >= 2.13).